# SymmetricDS transform_column

Tags: symmetricds

I am facing a problem about symmtericds transform_column :

-- transform to mst_author From EAut

```
insert into sym_transform_table(
transform_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, transform_point, source_table_name,
target_table_name, delete_action, transform_order, column_policy, update_first,
last_update_by, last_update_time, create_time
) values (
'mst_author_2_EAut', 'pusat', 'cabang1', 'EXTRACT', 'EAut',
'mst_author', 'DEL_ROW', 1, 'SPECIFIED', 1,
'sym', current_timestamp, current_timestamp
);

insert into sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, source_column_name, target_column_name, pk, transform_type,create_time, last_update_time)
values
('mst_author_2_EAut', '', 'AutId', 'author_id', 1, 'copy',current_timestamp, current_timestamp),
('mst_author_2_EAut', '', 'AutKey', 'author_name', 0, 'copy',current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, source_column_name, target_column_name, pk, transform_type,create_time, last_update_time,transform_expression)
values
('mst_author_2_EAut', '*', 'AutRaw', 'input_date', 0, 'variable',current_timestamp, current_timestamp,'system_date');
```

The errors:

> Failed sql was: insert into buku.mst_author () values ()
>   --------------> empty column and values
>
> Failed sql parameters: []
>
> Failed sql parameters types: []
>
> Failed row data was: "112950","1","0","0"," ","Name","\last,
>   first","100" [cabang1-001] - DataLoaderService - Failed to load batch
>   000-92 org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Field 'author_name' doesn't
>   have a default val ue at
>   org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate

Any help is appreciated

notes:
AutId is SQL Server Identity and author_id is MySQL auto increment

Answer (score 0):

There's a column 'author_name' at the target node that either doesn't exist at the source or its value is null. If there's a constraint 'not null' at the target declare a default value by 'alter table mst_author add constraint not null default value '' on column author_name' or something along these lines

I would recommend to add all source and target column transformations even if the column names are equal, not only the ones that are different

Comment: Thanks for reply,but the column `author_name` is exists and i think the problem is generated insert sql is empty in parameters and values 

`Failed sql was: insert into buku.mst_author () values () --------------> empty column and values`

Comment: What's the value of that column at the source table?

Comment: The columns and values are  `AutId = 52412, AutKey = 'bbb' ` from the source table `EAut`.If I don't do the table and column transformation it works fine (table EAut is generated in target catalog and data inserted).

Comment: yes, but what's the value of the column 'author_name' at the source? Does it exist on the source node?

Comment: the value is bbb and the table name on the source node is `AutKey`

Comment: I can see that. What is the value of the column author_name of the column AuthKey at the source?

Comment: the value is `bbb` (varchar)

Comment: it the name of the column author_name the same at the source and at the target node? also I can't see 'bbb' being loaded at the target node. there are other values but not this one

Comment: the column name is not same.I have had a table transform in this SymmetricDS query,the SQL query is on my question above.

Comment: I found the problem  : Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with text, but the datatype is varchar(96) not varbinary?